# How can I mount a multi-partition img file on macOS?

Tags: macos, mount

I have an img file that has several partitions in it.

When I mount it with DiskImageMounter, I just see the first partition but I can't find a way to access the other partitions.

I don't see an option in `fdisk` either.

The diskutil output is:

```
 /dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +31.9 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 BOOT                    67.1 MB    disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         2.1 GB     disk2s2
   3:                      Linux                         29.5 GB    disk2s3
```

It's an image for the Raspberry Pi and it is supposed to be written directly on a SD card.

Comment: ok, just used ext4fuse and it's working perfectly! thanks!

Comment: BTW You do not need to mount the image to write it to the SD card using `dd`. As long as the size of the image is at least slightly smaller then the size of the SD card there shouldn't  be an issue. Have a look a this from Raspberry Pi Org: [Installing operating system images on Mac OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md)

Comment: I was trying to extract the files to sort them as I don't have a SD card of the right size :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**macOS** does not natively support or mount **Linux** partitions. You'll need to install some third-party utilities to be able to mount, e.g. **ext2**, **ext3** or **ext4** formatted partitions/disks.

[FUSE for macOS](https://osxfuse.github.io/) comes to mind, along with [ex4fuse](https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse).